# The stable and unstable sets of the torus are dense

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, abstract-algebra, dynamical-systems

I know this might be much to read since I reference paragraphs from the book. I hope that the question is not too cluttered.

The $n$-torus is defined to be the set of all equivalence classes under the equivalence relation that any two points in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are equivalent if and only if their coordinates differ by an integer. And the hyperbolic toral automorphism is defined by

Definition. Let $L_{A}(x) = A \cdot x$, where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix such that

(1) All entries of $A$ are integers;
(2) $\det (A) = \pm 1$; (3) $A$ is hyperbolic, i.e. none of its eigenvalues have absolute value $1$.

**I am trying to prove the following statement**

Proposition. If $[p] \in T^{n}$, then the stable set $W^{s}[p]$ at $[p]$ and the unstable set $W^{u}[p]$ are dense in $T^{n}$.

However, **I do not understand what the stable and unstable sets actually are for the** $n$-torus. I believe that the reason I cannot even begin with attempting a proof is that the book never defined the stable and unstable sets for dimension $n$, but only for $2$. In the book, for the $2$-torus, the author says the following

[image]

After which he presents the proof for the $2$-dimensional case that the stable and unstable sets are dense given by

[image]

**EDIT:** This is the definition that Devaney gives for the stable $W^{s}$ and unstable $W^{u}$ subspaces. I believe that $L$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ into $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

[image]

Comment: "I believe that the reason I cannot even begin with attempting a proof is that the book never defined the stable and unstable sets for dimension $n$, but only for $2$." So the problem is the book (besides using a notation never used in the theory, Devaney...) and if so the question is for your teacher. What is your question other than this?

Comment: @JohnB I am trying to prove that the stable and unstable sets of a point in the $n$-torus are dense on the $n$-torus. The book does it for the $2$-torus. And in order to do this I first tried understanding the proof of the book given for the case $n = 2$.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the stable and unstable sets on any dimension?

Comment: Yes. For the 1-dimensional case, the stable set is the set of all forward asymptotic points to a periodic point $p$ of period $n$. And the unstable set is the set of all backward asymptotic points of $p$. This is the definition given by Devaney. I will check the book for the defintion Devaney gives in terms of dimension $2$ and get back to you.

Comment: @JohnB The definition was too long for the comments so I made an edit to the post at the bottom.

Comment: OK. For example, if the stable set is a plane in dimension $3$, then you need to keep extending that plane on the torus and somehow think of the projections on each direction to obtain densedness. Think about it!

Comment: So if I want to extend this definition to case $n$, then should I induct? Since now, we can have $n$ eigenvalues and not just three. So I choose $|\lambda_{1}|, \ldots, |\lambda{n - 1}| < 1$ and $|\lambda_{n}| > 1$. And then the stable set will be an object of dimension $n - 1$ and the unstable set an object of dimension $n - 2$? Or do these objects remain planes and lines?